# I cannot create new tables for migration

Tags: mysql, yii2

I am running

```
./yii migrate/create create_junction_table_for_sales_and_branch_tables --fields="created_at:dateTime"
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known.
```

Trying to create an ordinary table also gives the same error. I cannot solve this issue.

This is part of my code in `common/config/main.php`:

```
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=' . getenv('DB_HOST') . ';port='. 
getenv('DB_PORT', 3306) .';dbname=' . getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'username' => getenv('DB_USERNAME'),
        'password' => getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
```

Comment: have you provided your environment variables? this will vary based on the host OS
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable

otherwise if on unix, you may run

telnet your.mysql.host.name 3306

and it should not timeout

Comment: I still don't really get what you mean. I thought the code above set the environment variables and I don't even know what the nodename or servname variables ahould be or how i would set them.

Comment: The code above gets the values from the environment variables, hence the function name 'getenv'. You may hard code your database credentials, replacing the getenv, so you won't need to set the environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **best** way to configure your db connection is:

```php
return [
    'class' => \yii\db\Connection::class,
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=address:port;dbname=mydatabase',
    'username' => 'admin',
    'password' => '123321',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

Also you can **define** variables in yor cfg file, and use them, don't forget, that env.variables, which you are using, **must be defined in your environment**

```php
// You may define env.variable in your system.
$host = 'localhost'; 
$port = '3306'; 
$dbname = 'mydatabase';
$username = 'admin';
$password = '123321';
$charset = 'utf8';

return [
    'class' => \yii\db\Connection::class,
    'dsn' => "mysql:host={$host}:{$port};dbname={$dbname}",
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'charset' => $charset,
];
```

You can customize variables as you want, also you may write methods, **before** returning connection class, to get all *needed* variables.